# NSTableView outlet subclassed to NSOutlineView in code?

Tags: swift, macos, nstableview, subclassing

Here's a question I can't manage to find any advice about (probably due to my bad english during search on the net: hence the bad title!).

I have a subclass of a NSTableView in a xib which is used several times in different windows. But in one of these windows, I want the tableView to behave as an NSOutlineView (but also benefit from the nice features I added).
I am reluctant to simply create a subclass of an outlineView and copy all the code from the tableView subclass to it, as I want to reuse the same code (easier code maintenance), and the xib as well. How should I do?

Josh

Comment: Try creating a category that provides features by default implementations which your classes can conform to.

Comment: categories per se don't exist in Swift; do you mean protocol extensions? And if so it can't use any of the stored properties of the involved classes

Answer (score 0):

If your subclass has no additional stored properties, and you don't need to override initializers, declare your methods in an extension clause to `NSTableView` instead of a subclass:

```
extension NSTableView {
   func forAllSubclassesOfNSTableView() { /* etc. */ }
}


let ov = NSOutlineView()
ov.forAllSubclassesOfNSTableView() // Works
```

Comment: thanks, but actually, my subclass does have lots of properties, and initializers as well. Actually, it's not only a NSTableView, but a NSView that contains several objects: buttons, labels + this Table view. When I use this NSView in a window, I just want to say to its TableView: "Hey, this time, I want you to behave like an outlineView". Does it make sense?